# setting tabindex in firefox ends up tabbing into the browser tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, accessibility, tabindex

so I have an app with several buttons:

```
<button tabindex='1'></button>
<button tabindex='2'></button>
<button tabindex='3'></button>
```

however tabbing ends up moving the tab focus to the actual tab of the browser instead of going to the next button (ie. it ends up focusing on Firefox's tab user interface instead of tabbing into the website's button)...any idea why this could possibly happen?

note: I can't paste in the real code I use since it is much more complicated and involves complicated javascript, etc hence it's difficult to paste them in into here however the change I made was that I made 3 button elements have tabindex attributes in ascending 1,2,3 order...

Comment: Make an simple example that reproduces the issue. It doesn't have to be your production code

Comment: You need to give the button a text

Comment: im having this same issue